# How to use Elasticsearch with Meteorjs

Tags: elasticsearch, meteor, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

I want to use the elastic search with my meteor application  please suggest the best way to achieve the same.

Currently I have used mongoDB and I want to use both elastic and MongoDB in my meteor application.

Answer (score 0):

You can check a guide here on how to integrate Elastic with Meteor: https://medium.com/@chrnwsk/integrating-elasticsearch-with-meteor-6b5b1df47869